# Shortcut for a chunk of rest code

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

In sphinx I want to have a command, which would expand differently depending on withter I'm making an html build or a latex build. Example:

```
.. |noindent| replace::

   .. only:: latex

      .. raw:: latex

         \noindent

   .. only:: html

      .. rst-class:: noindent
```

The problem is that `replace` can't accept multiline string: it can only accept a single line string:

```
.. |noindent| replace:: with this
```

Is there a way to have a shortcut binded to a chunk of rest code?

**Edit**:

One can just include the source of course:

- ReST:

  ```
  .. include:: _noindent.rst
  ```
- `_noindent.rst`:

  ```
  .. only:: latex

     .. raw:: latex

        \noindent

  .. only:: html

     .. rst-class:: noindent
  ```

but the drawback is to keep track of `_noindent.rst`: either setting correct link, or copying the file to every content folder.

**Edit 2**:

Perhaps it won't be hard for guy experienced with sphinx to add a custom directive

```
text with indent

.. noindent::

text with no indent
```

which would expand to the above code.

Comment: You have a typo in your code. Once you write ``noindnet`` (wrong spelled) and once ``noindent``. Is this also in your productive code? Please correct it as it can be very annoying to the readers.

Comment: @cezar: Fixed that, sorry.